# Yes no string in C

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I've searched the forums, and I can't seem to find an answer that is suitable for my specific problem (I tried Google as well).  I seem to be having an issue comparing the strings ("Yes", "yes", "No", "no") correctly.  I tried an if else originally, but I think a while loop is more efficient.  Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double far = 0;
double cel = 0;
double userValue = 0;
double endResult = 0;
int choice;
char *decision = "";


int main() 
{  
 conversion();
 return 0;   
}

conversion() {
   printf("Please enter a 1 for Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion OR\n a 2 
   for 
   Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion\n");

scanf("%d", &choice);

   if(choice == 1) {
     printf("Please enter a value for Celsius.  Example 32 or 32.6\n");
     scanf("%lf", &userValue);
     endResult = (userValue * (9.0/5.0) + 32);
     printf("%lf\n", endResult);
     yesOrNo();
} 

else 

printf("Please enter a value for Fahrenheit.  Example 212 or 212.6\n");
scanf("%lf", &userValue);
endResult = (userValue -32) * (5.0/9.0);
printf("%lf\n", endResult);
yesOrNo();

}


yesOrNo() {

printf("Do you want to continue?    Enter Yes or No\n");
scanf(" %s", &decision);   

 while(decision == "Yes" || decision == "yes") {

    conversion();

 }

 exit(0);

}
```

Comment: don't use == comparator for strings Use `stricmp` instead

Comment: You need to use `strcmp` to compare the contents of strings, otherwise you're just comparing if they are at the same address or not.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: Note that you're going into recursion on each conversion: main() calls conversion(), conversion calls yesOrNo(), yesOrNo() calls conversion, and so on. You're risking a stack overflow exception.

Comment: `char *decision = "";`... `scanf(" %s", &decision);`-- this is wrong. `decision` is a pointer to an empty string. You need an array to hold the user input, e.g., `char decision[100];`. Then use `scanf("%99s", decision);` to get user input.

Comment: Yep, that's how I solved the problem, although I didn't use that exact approach.  It occurred to me moments after I posted.  I think just posting the question made me think about what I was doing wrong.  Thanks for the responses guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't have strings. You have to use the function strcmp() to compare string literals and/or null-terminated character arrays.

```
decision == "Yes"
```

should be

```
strcmp(decision,"Yes") == 0
```

Comment: I figured out the problem moments after I posted.  In fact, I couldn't even submit my response before it was closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare string literals using `==` operator you need to use `strcasecmp()`() or `stricmp()` function which are case insensitive.
If the strings are equal `strcasecmp()` and `stricmp()` return 0, if first argument is greater than second it returns **positive number** else **negative**.

Comment: stricmp in this occurrence

Comment: The POSIX case-insensitive string comparison function is `strcasecmp()` declared in `<strings.h>`, IIRC

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, you have right just checked, thank you very much!!

Comment: `You can't compare string literals using ==` It does not matter if it is a literal or not. You can of course compare them using the `==` as well but you compare the pointers not the objects referenced by them

Comment: @ PeterJ_01, yes totally agree, what i meant is that by using `==` operator will not get the result that expected which is to compare the strings, thanks for comment !!